# C# - How to get source code of a program in string variable for parsing?

Tags: c#, string, quotes

I am trying to parse the code of a MainForm.cs file. As you can imagine it contains texts like:

```
string name = "Name: "+var1;
```

I presume the code below will just break on the first quotes it finds?

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Project\MainsForm.cs");
```

So what would work?

Comment: The line you posted will read the contents of the entire file into the string variable (provided it's not greater than 2 Gb in size!).  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Quotes only cause errors in string _literals_.

Comment: I admit that I have not tested it since I believed this method had an extraordinary chance of failure.. If you are correct then I apologize and the question can be deleted. Will parsing be a problem, or is that as easy as using .Replace method?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @JNYRanger Beginner self-modifying AI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ReadAllText` method will read the entire file, quotation marks and all.  When you parse it, the string will contain quotation marks.  There is nothing in C# that prevents strings from containing quotation marks.  For example, one could define a string as:

```
string quotedValue = "This string contains some \"air quotes\"";
```

And it would work.